# How to modify display of spinner's listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-spinner

In my Android App, I am trying to display a ListView on the click event of Spinner. I have tried to do this but getting some problem.

1. The Down Arrow which I have used in my customized Spinner that arrow image is also coming in ListView of Spinner.
2. On the Click Listener of Spinner I want a List to be shown like below Image,

[image]

ListView After Click on Spinner,

[image]

[image]

```
String[] spinnervalues={"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addpassengers);
    Spinner myspinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    myspinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, spinnervalues));

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
    {
        return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) 
    {
        return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myspinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
        TextView spinnertext = (TextView) myspinner
                .findViewById(R.id.spinnertext);
        spinnertext.setText(spinnervalues[position]);
        return myspinner;
    }

}
```

custom_spinner.xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3px" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:padding="3px"
    android:text="JMD Grp"
    android:textColor="#0022ee"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Rightend Arrow -->
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/downarrowiv" 
    android:layout_width="15dip"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom_spinnerlist.xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3px" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:padding="3px"
    android:text="JMD Grp"
    android:textColor="#0022ee"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have gone through many examples but didn't get my desired result.

Is this due to version of android ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to show your Spinner list on the below the spinner not on the hole screen ?

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee: I want the list same as Image.

Answer (score 1):

R.layout.custom_spinner is the layout for your spinner or the items in the list?  Guessing that you would need to change line

```
View myspinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
```

to something like

```
View myspinner = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
```

and change

```
TextView spinnertext = (TextView) myspinner
                .findViewById(R.id.spinnertext);
```

to

```
TextView spinnertext = (TextView) myspinner
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Comment: I am using custom_spinner layout. So thats why I have written that line.

Comment: and the purpose of using this custom_layout is to display a down arrow image at the right

Comment: @Android correct, but you are using the same view for the list, that is the problem I am pointing to.  Inflate a different view there and you won't have the arrow.

Comment: Resource id cant found. I think it should be `android.R.layout.spinner_item`

Comment: Resource id cant be found.
@MikeIsrael: I want list same as Image shown above.

Comment: @Android that is because I was giving an example name for something you need to make. You could use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, but I recommend creating your own resource. I have edited my answer for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, but I recommend you create your own resource

Comment: I have already made my own resource and I have updated that xml file in my post.

Comment: @Android correct that is the resource for the un-opened spinner not for the list items.  You should have a separate resource for each.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45643/discussion-between-android-and-mikeisrael)

Comment: Please let me know how to create custom_spinnerlist.
Should I use ListView in my Custom Layout?

Comment: @Android could be the same as custom_spinner.xml without the ImageView.  You can play with the height and such to suit your needs.

Comment: I have done same as you said but now that down arrow image is not coming in spinner view too..

Comment: @Android you created a new file or changed custom_spinner?  You need two files, and also I highly recommend you review some of the basic Android development material because it seems that would solve a lot of the confusion here.

Comment: Created new file. Updated my post.

Comment: @Android you need to change the lines listed in my answer (in getCustomView) for it to work.  Did you change them as well?  The question was not updated accordingly if so.